# How to set font-family correctly in a bilingual text in a Nuxt-Strapi app?

Tags: css, fonts, nuxt.js, strapi

Currently I am building a website with [nuxt-js](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/get-started/installation). For the back-end of site I am using [strapi](https://strapi.io/) headless CMS. In article pages of the site I get data (text of articles) from **rich text** capability of strapi database. So I don't need to define **html** tags to load the content correctly. The main language of the site is Persian, but there are some English words between sentences. For better design and showing content I used two font-family in my website. The `font1` variable in my CSS file is referenced to a Persian font-family and the `font2` is referenced to an English font-family. When I use this code in my CSS file:

```
#app {
    font-family: var(--font1), var(--font2);
}
```

I get this result in the browser page:

[image: result-one image]

As you could see the number 5 in the text is rendered in Persian language (correct format), but the number 8 in **laravel-8** word also is rendered in Persian (wrong format). If I change the code to this one:

```
#app {
    font-family: var(--font2), var(--font1);
}
```

I get the reverse result:

[image: result-two image]

As you could notice none of the above results are correct. If I used html tags in my pages, I could wrap that words in for example `span` tags and define custom CSS for them. But in my case I don't use html tags and they are rendered automatically by strapi. So how could I fix this issue in my website? Is there any CSS property or any other trick that could solve this problem?

Comment: It appears the text content contains ASCII (European) digits, but you want instances within Arabic-script runs to have the font substitute Indo-Arabic digits. Why not have the text content contain the specific digits intended in each case---5 where needed, but ۵ where that's needed?

Comment: @PeterConstable I did not understand what you mean exactly. If you say that English words and Persian words become separate, I said in the question that my text is in Persian, but there are some words and expressions in English that are between the sentences. Also the goal is that **the client** (who does not have coding knowledge) could insert their text inside strapi CMS. If you have any solution that works with **nuxt-strapi** please post the answer for me, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [@nuxtjs/markdownit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/markdownit) package, I finally found this solution. After adding that package according to its documentation, we must add `html: true` in its configuration as the code below:

> nuxt.config.js file:

```
markdownit: {
    preset: 'default',
    linkify: true,
    breaks: true,
    injected: true,
    html: true,
},
```

So the texts that we insert in strapi **rich-text** data could have `html tags` like `span` inside. So I can wrap my **English** words to a `span` tag with the class of **englishText** like the text below:

> strapi rich text:

```
در میان ویژگی&zwnj;هایی که در CSS برای تعریف  کردن 5 استایل استفاده می&zwnj;شوند، شاید یکی از جذاب&zwnj;ترین و البته گسترده&zwnj;ترین آنها <span class="englishText">laravel-8</span>  باشد.
```

Then when we use `this.$md.render(this.text);` in our nuxt app (suppose that `this.text` is the data that contains rich-text from **strapi**) and use that text in our template part, If we define the `englishText` class in our CSS as the code below:

```
span.englishText {
/* font2 is the English font and font1 is the Persian font */
  font-family: var(--font2), var(--font1);
}
```

We could get the correct result as this one:

[image: result image]